# sqlite append column to existing table

Tags: sql, sqlite, datatable, syntax, append

I have a table(MyTable) with 3 columns named as "A","B",and "C".
Now, I use SELECT and LENGTH function like SELECT LENGTH("A") FROM MyTable.
So, I just got another column with rows of characters length from each row of column A.
However, I have no clue to append this to MyTable.

In other words, if my question is rephrased, I wonder how to make another column with characters length of a certain column.

I tried to make new table with the column made from SELECT LENGTH("A") FROM, and CREATE new table AS SELECT LENGTH("A") FROM. But, it shows syntax error.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If you need the length of a value, select it. Columns should store data itself, not data of data.

Comment: It is `LENGTH` and not `LENTH`.

Comment: I fixed question. I typed LENGTH correctly, but just made a type when I'm typing this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the error you are getting is because you are not specifying name for the new column. Can you try this:

```
CREATE TABLE NewTable AS SELECT A, B, C, LENGTH(A) AS A_length FROM MyTable;
```

---

As @forpas said, your syntax error was caused by a typo - using `LENTH` instead of `LENGTH`.

Comment: This is wrong. The new table can be created without errors even if the derived column is not aliased: https://dbfiddle.uk/dQ4N1bjj The problem was a typo `LENTH` instead of `LENGTH`.